# npm global install not using node

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm trying to create a package that can be installed globally. My package.json has:

```
{
  "name": "my-new-package",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "preferGlobal": true,
  "bin": {
    "my-new-package": "index.js"
  }
}
```

I can run it with "node index.js" and I can publish it to npm.

The problem is that when I install it globally `npm i -g my-new-package`, on Windows the file `my-new-package.cmd` is:

`@"%~dp0\node_modules\my-new-package\index.js"   %*`

So when I execute `my-new-package` it opens the javascript file with the default editor.

In contrast, other global packages use `node.exe`. Here's the `cute-files.cmd` example:

```
@IF EXIST "%~dp0\node.exe" (
  "%~dp0\node.exe"  "%~dp0\node_modules\cute-files\cute-files.js" %*
) ELSE (
  @SETLOCAL
  @SET PATHEXT=%PATHEXT:;.JS;=;%
  node  "%~dp0\node_modules\cute-files\cute-files.js" %*
```

btw, I get the same behavior when I install it on Linux.

So how can I configure my package to use node when it's installed globally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how to create a globally executable nodejs package

```
mkdir my-new-package
cd my-new-package
```

first create     `cat package.json`

```
{
  "name": "my-new-package",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "global module my-new-package",
  "main": "./lib/index.js",
  "bin": {
    "my-executable-name": "./bin/test-module.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
    "preferGlobal": "true"
}
```

now make these two dirs as children of dir `my-new-package`

```
mkdir bin
mkdir lib
```

here is the another file we need `cat lib/index.js`

```
var sayHello = function(name) {
 return 'Hello, ' + name;
};

// Allows us to call this function from outside of the library file
// Without this, the function would be private to this file

exports.sayHello = sayHello;
```

now create a file   `cat bin/test-module.js`

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

var lib= require('../lib/index.js');
var greeting = lib.sayHello('hello everyone');

console.log(greeting);
```

now get into dir `my-new-package` where file `package.json` lives and issue the global install command

```
cd my-new-package

npm install -g .
```

notice the period in above install command

its output will be something like this

```
/home/stens/node-v6.5.0/bin/my-new-package -> /home/stens/node-v6.5.0/lib/node_modules/my-new-package/bin/test-module.js
/home/stens/node-v6.5.0/lib
└── my-new-package@1.0.0
```

now that its globally installed you can issue this while in any directory

```
my-executable-name
```

and it will respond with

```
Hello, hello everyone
```

Interestingly our new executable lives in nodejs global bin directory as per

```
which my-executable-name
```

which responds with

```
/home/stens/node-v6.5.0/bin/my-executable-name
```